# Error "no key for alias" during app signing in google play

Tags: android, google-play, apk, signing, android-keystore

I'm trying to use the pepk tool during google play app signing,like [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) and I get the error no key for alias. what is the reason?

Comment: my questing is about google play app signing, and I didnt find that question when searching for an answer , so I think your link is nice for addition but not duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that the alias is not correct ? 
maybe you thought the alias is exactly like the keystore name.
one way to know what is the alias ,is to start the "generate signed apk" process inside android studio: press build-> generate signed apk,and then find your 
keystore.when you choose the keystore ,you will see the alias name inside the 
"key alias:" field .